# how can i select specific text files using glob2 library

Tags: python

i have been working on this code and i wanted to know what would i need to do if there is a way to select specific files instead of all of the files with the same extension

```
import glob2
from datetime import datetime



filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt")
with open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".txt", 'w') as file:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(str(filename), "r") as f:
            file.write(f.read() + "\n")
```

i have tried getting the specific files in a tuple or list and it wouldn't work

Comment: If you want specific files then you should not ask for all the files with a certain extension. That's what glob does.

Answer (score 1):

You can try storing your text files in and checking if the files from `filenames` exist in it:

```
import glob2

files = {'file1.txt', 'file2.txt'} # can use list or tuple here also

filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt")
for file in filenames:
    if file in files:
        # Do something with file
```

Alternatively, you could just use [`os.listidr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), since you only want *specific* files:

```
from os import listdir

files = {'file1.txt', 'file2.txt'}

for file in listdir('.'):
    if file in files:
        # Do something with file
```